# Fixing a match clause warning by getting rid of a type parameter

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure, extractor

i want to implement the following exhaustive match, but i can't figure out to remove the type parameter and thus the warning that it is erased:

```
sealed trait Q[+V]
case object QEmpty extends Q[Nothing]
sealed trait QNonEmpty[V] extends Q[V] {
  def foo: V
}
final class QLeaf[V](val foo: V) extends QNonEmpty[V]
final class QNode[V](val foo: V, var children: Array[Q[V]]) extends QNonEmpty[V]

def test[V](n: Q[V]): String = n match {
  case QEmpty          => "empty"
  case n: QNonEmpty[V] => n.foo.toString  // warning: type parameter V is erased
}
```

in my concrete case the body of the `case n` match is very large, and i do not want to add more match clauses so that i match instead against `QLeaf` and `QNode` (because in my concrete case there are more than two subclasses, also they are mutable and thus shouldn't be case classes). the resolved type needs to be `QNonEmpty[V]`, it cannot be `QNonEmpty[_]`.

Can I create an extractor for `QNonEmpty` which matches both `QLeaf` and `QNode`?

Comment: p.s. no manifests please; and this is a performance critical bit, so please no extra object creations like `trait Q[ +V ] { def lift: Either[ QEmpty, QNonEmpty[ V ]]}`

Comment: The only way to write such an extractor is using isInstanceOf with concrete types. I guess you know how to do that?

Comment: @Kim Aehm, no, but I have written a few simple extractors, so surely can figure it out. A pity that cannot be done type safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use existential types to match on a type with erased parameters:

```
type AnyNonEmpty = QNonEmpty[X] forSome { type X }

in match {
  case x: AnyNonEmpty => //...
}
```

An extractor could look like this:

```
object QNonEmpty {
  def unapply(in: QNonEmpty[_]): Option[Any] = Some(in.foo)
}

def test[ V ]( n: Q[ V ]) : String = n match {
   case QEmpty => "empty"
   case QNonEmpty(foo) => foo.toString
}
```

I don't think that you can write a typesafe extractor though, as in your example code the type parameter to the method is also erased.
Maybe you should think about adding a `fold` method to your trait and rewrite your example like this:

```
sealed trait Q[ +V ] {
  def fold[A](e: => A, f: V => A): A = e
}

case object QEmpty extends Q[ Nothing ]

sealed trait QNonEmpty[ V ] extends Q[ V ] {
  def foo: V
  override def fold[A](e: => A, f: V => A) = f(foo)
}

// ...

def test[V](n: Q[V]) = n.fold("empty", _.toString)
```

Comment: Thanks. I kind of like the `fold` approach. In my case I have full control over `Q`, so adding that is no problem. (I still wonder what I'd do if `Q` came from some external library, though).